# Anythingslider switch params in responsive layout

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, anythingslider, window-resize

got a problem with the anythingslider,
anybody knowing how to refresh the slider on window.resize with new params?

I already tried it with a new call on resize. but it only works one time to the smaller layout.

```
function startSlideshow(){
    jQuery('#startslideshow')
    .anythingSlider({
        autoPlay : true,
        resizeContents : false,
        width : dynAnyWidth,
        height : dynAnyHeight,
..}
```

on resize i call the function with the new params..

thx for help.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of AnythingSlider, there is an `expand` option which automatically resizes AnythingSlider to fit inside of its parent element.

Check out [this demo](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/expand.html) with a fixed height and percentage width

or [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/1431/) with a dynamic width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var my_width = $(window).width();
    var my_height = $(window).height();

    // DO SOME MATH

    startSlideshow(my_width, my_height );
});

function startSlideshow(dynAnyWidth, dynAnyHeight){
    jQuery('#startslideshow')
    .anythingSlider({
        autoPlay : true,
        resizeContents : false,
        width : dynAnyWidth,
        height : dynAnyHeight,
}
```

Does that help at all?  Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: exactly, the problem is.. that the anythingslider does not toggle it's size. on call it a second, third.. time.